# Angular 4 animate any height/position changes with angular animations

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, animation, angular-animations

Pretty straight forward question I hope. Is there a way **using angular animations syntax** to animate any height or position changes on an element?

For example if a DOM element is removed causing another element to shift up, can the shift up be animated without having to set a state variable?

`<div [@positionChange]></div>`

Or something similar without state.

thanks in advance.

Comment: you can pass in values of height and position to make sure the animations stitch themselves accordingly

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you could just add a fold-animation to all the child elements that might be removed / added dynamicly. If the child height is animated, the container size is animated anyway.

```
trigger('fold', [
  transition(':enter', [style({height: 0, overflow: 'hidden'}), animate('.3s ease', style({height: '*'}))]),
  transition(':leave', [style({height: '*', overflow: 'hidden'}), animate('.3s ease', style({height: 0}))])
]);
```

Comment: I like this suggestion but the :enter and :leave alias only work for elements that are being removed or added from dom (void => *, * =>  void) so elements just being moved around are not animated.

Comment: Not sure if i understand your problem. But if an element folds smoothly, affected elements shift up smoothly.

Comment: This is close enough to what I wanted, thank you. This way you are still unable to control the type and duration of the animations on elements passively affected by the elements getting removed but does make the transitions smoother and cosistent.